# how to get the public key from let's encrypt files

Tags: ssl

I have generate a ssl certificate using let's encrypt, there contains `fullchain.pem` and `privkey.pem` files under my website nginx folder, how to get the public key from this files? what I want the public key may look like:

```
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
xxxxxx
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
```

I am using this command to generate the public key in the CentOS:

```
openssl rsa -in privkey.pem -pubout > key.pub
```

but the output file look like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA4KmZTSFF9BgWWILjaM87
NRsRb3Ptwaw5pne9UR1Ol8/PP9p6/37NRBVF+ruggPDFRY8G7nBQI5
ht7eNQQnJp7azHxzv+Wn70ujzLBJJuIZZJE3sEKcekNgWX9dH7hjiqwncmu8
yMXUHMnf0KQ559Sziucay4O4Ct2Ped6UMFx3Ysx8LnU0nRMS+GzYoAJdWcJk893d
5fZ9KkwaZBlkCaHulasQEyArUYDxB+w5PMOE1+bzjlxjjrtVl9lwsIiG4kG0/I6E
eXk1x/OU0DSEppqyhp9sR06HSM1ONB51RF8XUUwe1RRUIlTpeLfSZikpZgnSAbOw
pQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

I did not want this format, what should I do to get the correct public key? I want to format like this way:

```
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
xxxxxx
----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE----
```

Comment: `BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE` is for a certificate, not a public key. If you want a certificate, you already have one (from LetsEncrypt, plus the chain certs) in the files created by certbot where you will find `BEGIN/END CERTIFICATE`. If you want a public  key and not a certificate, `BEGIN/END PUBLIC KEY` _is_ a public key.

Comment: *...I did not want this format...* What format do you want?